# anova_lm() python: on which model type does it work?

Tags: python, r, glm, anova

I am new to Python and trying to transition to a unique platform, Python, from Matlab+R platforms.

I need to do a regression of my data.

After reading what is available online - unfortunately not as numerous as for R just yet - I realized that I need to play with the following options:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

mod1 = smf.glm(formula=formula_new, data=dta_new, family=sm.families.Gaussian())
mod2 = smf.ols(formula=formula_new, data=dta_new, family=sm.families.Gaussian())
mod3 = sm.OLS.from_formula(formula=formula_new, data=dta_new)
```

all three give me similar results.
What I really want to know is if there exists a function similar to `anova()` from R (with a nice table summarizing the comparison of different models, or within a model for different variables, as shown here http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-series-anova-tables/ ) for any of these model options.

I tried to run

```
table = sm.stats.anova_lm(modX)
print table
```

with X = 1,2,3, basically for all models (those coming from smf. or sm.) but I always get the same error:

```
AttributeError: 'OLS'/'GLM' object has no attribute 'model'
```

with OLS or GLM depending on the type of model.

thanks for any input. am I not importing correctly modules? I am confused.

Links to applications/examples/tutorials of python are welcome.

rpy2 is not an option on my server, I am working on getting R3.0 installed, but it might take a while.

Answer (score 0):

I figured why it wasn't working on all models.

`anova_lm()` wants the `fit()` attribute:

```
table = sm.stats.anova_lm(modX.fit())
print table
```

however, it works only with mod2 and mod3, therefore it would not work with GLM models.

Here some info I found online relevant to this issue. Hopefully it will be extended to GLM models soon.
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.pystatsmodels/11000